# Как передать значение обработчику?

Tags: jquery, php

Подскажите, столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Написал форму отправки сообщения. Все отправляется нормально, но нюанс в том, что в форме не отправляется вот что

```
 To:   <a href="<?php echo $myrow[id]; ?>"><?php echo $myrow[fname]; ?> <?php echo $myrow[lname]; ?></a>
```

А надо, чтобы передавались ещё и эти данные. Возможно ли это сделать? И как их принять потом в php? Вот jQuery скрипт? который отправляет данные из формы php-обработчику:

```
$(function () {
    $("#send").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "senmess.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) {
                $(".container").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удобства запишите эти данные в отдельные переменные. Например если в ссылку добавить id:

```
 To:   <a id="link" lname="<?= $myrow[lname] ?>" fname="<?= $myrow[fname] ?>" href="<?php echo $myrow[id]; ?>"><?= $myrow[fname]; ?> <?= $myrow[lname]; ?></a>

var href = $("#link").attr('href');
var fname = $("#link").attr('fname');
var lname = $("#link").attr('lname');

$(function () {
    $("#send").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "senmess.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {"vals[]": [href, fname, lname] },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) {
                $(".container").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```